# Does linkTo helper caches its value?

Tags: ember.js

The link generated as:

```
{{#linkTo mode filterB currentMode}}
```

shows a correct currentMode value when rendered first time, but then it gets stuck with that mode, and even currentMode get changed to a different value the link does not get updated. Here is a [demo code on GitHub](https://github.com/afurmanov/strange_link_to_behavior/blob/master/test.html)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{#with App}}
  <div>
    <div style="float:left;width:200px">
      Filters:
      <ul>
        <li>{{#linkTo mode filterA currentMode}}filterA{{/linkTo}}</li>
        <li>{{#linkTo mode filterB currentMode}}filterB{{/linkTo}}</li>
        <li>currentFilter: {{currentFilter}}</li>
        <li>currentMode: {{currentMode}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
    Modes:
      <ul>
        <li>{{#linkTo mode currentFilter modeA}}modeA{{/linkTo}}</li>
        <li>{{#linkTo mode currentFilter modeB}}modeB{{/linkTo}}</li>
        <li>currentFilter: {{currentFilter}}</li>
        <li>currentMode: {{currentMode}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/with}}
</script>

<script type='text/coffeescript'>
window.App = App = Ember.Application.create()
App.Router.map (match) ->
  match("/").to("home")
  match("/filter/:filter").to("filter", (match) ->
    match("/mode/:mode").to("mode")
    )

App.modeA = "modeA"
App.modeB = "modeB"
App.filterA = "filterA"
App.filterB = "filterB"
App.currentMode = "modeA"
App.currentFilter = "filterA"

App.FilterRoute = Em.Route.extend
  setupControllers: (controller, filter)->
    App.set('currentFilter', filter)
  serialize: (filter)->
    {filter:filter}
App.ModeRoute = Em.Route.extend
  setupControllers: (controller, mode)->
    App.set('currentMode', mode)
  serialize: (mode)->
    {mode:mode}
</script>
```

When currentMode set to modeB, ember.js correctly render its text value in filters list, but link /filter/filterA/mode/modeA remains unchanged, when it has to be re-rendered as /filter/filterA/mode/modeB. I am curious if such behavior is intentional, and if yes what a right way to fix it and what a rational for such behavior?

Thanks!

Update:
This code does what is intended:

```
{{#with currentMode}}
  <li>{{#linkTo mode "App.filterA" this}}filterA{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li>{{#linkTo mode "App.filterB" this}}filterB{{/linkTo}}</li>
{{/with}}
```

, thanks to [sly7-7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373254/sly7-7), it looks like 'linkTo' does not react on context changes. It is still not clear to me if it is intentional or not.

Comment: could you try to enclose stuff inside a {{#with currentMode}} block ? Without it, I suspect the template is not rerendered  when currentMode changes, and so the link remains the same.

Comment: The `<li>currentMode: {{currentMode}}</li>` renders updated mode, when `<li>{{#linkTo mode filterA currentMode}}filterA{{/linkTo}}</li>` does not and they are next to each other in the template, so I am pretty sure the template get re-rendered.

Comment: Actually I did try it and it works, I'm adding changes to the original post.